# How to find values that fall between two dates?

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match, vlookup

I have a key of the "Values I'm trying to look up", my "Data" and the date ranges in which they fall.

How would I create a function or VBA tool that will look up the values that match to the "Values I'm trying to look up" along with fall between the two dates?

I'd also like to make the out put comma delimited because multiple values can match from the key based on the date range.

I attempted a INDEX function (I think I am entering the references wrong):

```
=INDEX($I$3:$I$18,MATCH($I$3:$I$18,K2:L2351,IF(E2>=K$2:K$2351,IF(F2<=K$2:K$2351,IF(Value=K$2:K$2351,1))),0))
```

I'm a beginner with excel any help would be appreciated.

[image: [enter image description here]

I saw this vba on another forum but it does not incorporate the match/vlookup function.

```
    Function SingleCellExtract(LookupValue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer, Char As String)
'Updateby20150824
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRet As String
    For I = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
        If LookupRange.Cells(I, 1) = LookupValue Then
            If xRet = "" Then
                xRet = LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
            Else
                xRet = xRet & "" & LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
            End If
        End If
    Next
    SingleCellExtract = Left(xRet, Len(xRet) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: what value are you trying to return in column G?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. I am trying to populate G with only they codes that are in my key Column I, but appear in the date range column E and F. The source of these codes/dates are columns K and L.

Comment: So this function works, but how can I incorporate a match function into this so it only shows the values that are in my key? =INDEX(P$3:P$2351,SMALL(IF($O$3:$O$2351>=$J$1,IF($O$3:$O$2351<=$K$1,ROW($O$3:$O$2351)-ROW($O$3)+1)),ROWS(K$3:K3)))

Answer (score 0):

Finally Figured it out, here is the code:

```
    Sub Populate_Data()


ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AE$2350").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "S48", "SX3", "P49", "S25", "P28", "T50", "TBF", "TB5"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AE$2350").AutoFilter Field:=10, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "1/3/2020", 0, "12/31/2019")

Range("J:J,M:M,T:T").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

curName = ActiveSheet.Name

updatedsheet = curName + " 2019-2020"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

ActiveSheet.Name = updatedsheet

Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False

ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A100" & var1a).Formula = _
Replace("=B2-DAY(B2)+1{SOME_VAR}", "{SOME_VAR}", var1a)


ActiveSheet.Range("G1" & var1a).Formula = _
Replace("1/1/2019{SOME_VAR}", "{SOME_VAR}", var1a)


With Range("G1")
.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G1:G13"), Type:=xlFillMonths

End With


Range("H1").FormulaArray = "=TEXTJOIN("","",TRUE,IF($A$1:$A$53=G1,$C$1:$D$53,""""))"
Range("H1:H13").FillDown

ActiveSheet.Range("I1" & var1a).Formula = _
Replace("=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$5,$A$2:$A$5,""=""&G1){SOME_VAR}", "{SOME_VAR}", var1a)

Range("I1:I13").FillDown

Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```